# Am I using get_or_create correctly?

Tags: django

Trying to use a single view for update and create operations.

I employ two different urls:

```
url(r'^update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', BoardUpdateView.as_view(), name='board-update'),
url(r'^update/$', BoardUpdateView.as_view(), name='board-create'),
```

Then I use this as my class:

```
class BoardUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Board
    fields = ['author']

    context_object_name = 'board'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        if "pk" not in self.kwargs:
            self.kwargs['pk']=None
        obj, created = Board.objects.get_or_create(pk=self.kwargs['pk'],
             defaults={'author': self.request.user})

      return obj
```

I know there are many ways to use Python, but I wondered if this approach is going to lead to any issues, or if there is a more idiomatic way to do this?  For example, my check for whether `pk` exists or not seems weird/gross.

Comment: You could condense it a little with a ternary operator, but I don't see any problem with the logic or anything.

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
def get_object(self, queryset=None):
    obj, created = Board.objects.get_or_create(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'),
         defaults={'author': self.request.user})

  return obj
```

This way, you don't have to check if `pk` exists in `kwargs`. `self.kwargs.get('pk')` will give you `pk` if it there, otherwise it will give you `None`. To make it more explicit, you can do this:

```
self.kwargs.get('pk', None)
```